# Men undergarments with Gymnastics shorts question

Tags: gymnastics

I just bought Men Gymnastics shorts from GK Elite. Like these pictures,
https://www.gkelite.com/collections/gk-gym-men-pants-and-shorts

In Women's Gymnastics, they don't wear undergarments underneath leotards.
However, I assume Men wear undergarments FruitLoom/Hanes (boxers, underwears) with Gymnastics shorts, correct?

I just started gymnastics and some of these shorts go lower than my Hanes boxers, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been practicing artistic gymnastics for many years and all male athletes wear brief panties. they must fit and hold up well! Any comfortable shorts on top are fine.